# close to forty-five thousand people

Tags: determiners

No one else could carry **close to** forty-five thousand people in such a short amount of time.

-- Markus Zusak, The Book Thief

There seems to be almost no other explanation but determiner or quantifier for ‘close to’ in the context. But I don’t find it on grammar books. What role does the phrase do?

Comment: *close to* acts as an adverb modifying 45,000. It is  equivalent to 'nearly' or 'almost'.

Comment: [Cleanliness is **next to** godliness](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Cleanliness+is+next+to+godliness)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It functions literally to express **distance** from the number 45,000:

1. Someone could carry **45,000** people in that short amount of time.
2. Anyone else would be able to carry **far fewer** people in that short amount of time.

In other words, this unnamed person is **far and away the best** at carrying people in a short amount of time.  This makes the phrase "close to" emphatic:

> This unnamed person could carry **far more** people than anyone else in this short amount of time.  Others could not carry **nearly as many** people.

This has approximately the same meaning.

Comment: Seems to me you're expanding the scope of the negative. You may be right in this instance, but I'd read it as "No one else could carry as much as he could, nearly 45,000" rather than as "What everyone else could carry was nowhere close to the 45,000 he could".

Comment: @StoneyB, I've found the quantifier account on [wiktionay.org](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/close_to): "It lasted 'close to' an hour"

Comment: @Listenever Yes, *close to* is not in question: it means "nearly". The difficulty - and it's sort of built in to the language - is to know whether the the sentence means a) what he could carry was nearly 45K, or b) what everybody else could carry was *not nearly* - i.e., far less than - 45K. I incline toward a), snailplane inclines toward b).

Comment: @StoneyB: I think this is one of those contexts where the written form doesn't necessarily reflect possible variations in the *spoken* form. If you say it with exaggerated stress on the word ***close***, snailboat's interpretation seems quite natural to me. But given that *could* be indicated by italicising the word, I suppose yours would normally be the most likely reading.

Comment: I think this answer may be misleading in that it could be read to say that the phrase "close to" indicates that this is unusual, something that most people could not do. The sentence as a whole says that, but "close to" by itself has no such connotation. It is quite reasonable to say, for example, "Most American men weigh close to 200 pounds". The point is that "close to" means "approximately", usually "slightly less than".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I think this genuinely ambiguous; and absent any positive indication that the negative embraces *close to*, I incline to the 'default' reading that it does not.

Comment: Yeah, well you're always more inclined to think in terms of *"the [default] **reading*** than me (because you've got a background in theatre?). By which I mean the question of how best to convert/interpret a written text into a spoken form. Personally I tend to *start* from the spoken form. Where this "ambiguity" we're looking here at simply wouldn't normally arise (you'd almost certainly *already* have dispelled any possible ambiguity by choosing to stress either ***else*** or ***close***, depending on which meaning you intended).